# How can I prevent this optical illusion of a rotated text?

Tags: text, interface-design, optical-illusion

Recently I have been trying to add tabs to my application. When designing the *Zoom* tab, I find that when focusing on other elements of the screen it appears to look like *eoon* to the unfocused eye. This is a really important feature and it is quite distracting to see this optical illusion.

Should I try a different font? Should I use a different size? Different color scheme? I could do images instead but I would rather do text.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could [use an icon instead](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=zoom).

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to find a solution without seeing the content with which has to face the button. Here are some suggestions:

- Use capital letters, lower case letters are always more illegible
- Try a vertical alignment, it's easier to confuse an *m* with an upper case *E* than a Z
- In a vertical alignment, use a monospaced font, in this case all the letters will have the same height and width
- Try a font with a square structure
- Slab fonts are more legible than sans serif fonts

[image]

Comment: Small note: In your sketch, I would increase the (vertical) letter spacing slightly (probably just one pixel) to avoid the letters merging at a quick glance.